# Python Classes hierarchy

Tags: python

having the nex class:

```
class Person(object):
    name = ""
    arrayTest = []
    def __init__(self, name, item):
        self.name = name
        self.arrayTest.append(item)

    def speak(self):
        print "Hi! My name is ", self.name
        print "And my sons are: "
        print self.arrayTest


basil = Person("Basil", "Sofia")
basil = Person("Basil", "Julia")
basil.speak()

>>> Hi! My name is  Basil
And my sons are:
['Sofia', 'Julia']

polly = Person("Polly", "Peter")
polly.speak()

>>>Hi! My name is  Polly
And my sons are:
['Sofia', 'Julia', 'Peter']
```

I would expect the second instance returns only Peter as son of Polly but it was not,

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: When you put `arrayTest = []` directly in the class and outside `__init__` like that you're telling Python you want to share this list between every instance of the class. That is how you create **shared class variables**, which is not what you want. It's a very common mistake but I don't have a good duplicate target in-hand.

Comment: By the way, also the output of `basil.speak()` should surprise you.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!! Andrea Corbellini

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!!  Two-Bit Alchemist